# Split SQL data into 3 columns using delimiter

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vba, excel

I am using Excel VBA and connecting to PGSQL using OleDB. Unfortunately oledb does not allow references to columns outside of an aggregate function where group by has been applied to the table, so I have to concatenate the data, but I'm having trouble splitting the data (latestBMI) back out into 3 separate columns (eventdate|weight|bmi), because the weight and bmi values vary in length, but are divided by a pipe delimter.

Here is what the table looks like through extraction:

```
master_id :   latestBMI
251       :   2008-05-08|84|26.8
2848      :   1992-11-23|86.71|27.3
2026      :   2002-04-16|105|31.6
22316     :   2014-02-28|107.955|35.1
16633     :   2005-07-04|70|25
9545      :   1997-04-08|82.73|24.9
```

I have been playing with various methods trying SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX, LEN, LEFT|RIGHT, but failing.
Here is my current code but the SUBSTRING elements for weight and bmi are my problem:

> ```
> Const sqlconnection = "Provider=oledb;"
>
> Dim conn As New Connection
> conn.ConnectionString = sqlconnection
> conn.Open
> Dim rs As Recordset
>
> Sheets("Sheet1").Select
> Range("A1").Select
>
> Dim DATA As String
> DATA = "SELECT latest.master_id, " _
> & "SUBSTRING(latestBMI,1,10) eventdate, " _
> & "SUBSTRING(latestBMI,12,CHARINDEX('|',latestBMI,RIGHT(latestBMI,7)) weight, " _
> & "SUBSTRING(latestBMI,20,4) BMI " _
> & "FROM ( " _
> & "SELECT master_id, " _
> & "MAX(CAST(eventdate AS VARCHAR(10)) + '|' + RIGHT(weightkg,7)+ '|' + RIGHT(bmi,4)) AS latestBMI " _
> & "FROM weight " _
> & "GROUP BY master_id) as latest " _
> & "LEFT JOIN person p on latest.master_id = p.entity_id "
>
> Set rs = conn.Execute(DATA)
> With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
>     .Refresh
> End With
> ```

How do I get them into 3 separate columns using the pipe delimiter?

Comment: How many records do you have?

Comment: There could be thousands of rows of data

Comment: You have tagged this with mysql and sql-server but in your question you state postgre. Which DBMS are you actually using??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with fetching the data first and then splitting it once its in the table, try this (if you know your latestBMI data will be in the range B2:B7)

> Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B2:B7"), _ 
>      DataType:=xlDelimited, _ 
>      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote,  _ 
>      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False,  _ 
>      Tab:=False,  _ 
>      Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True,  _ 
>      OtherChar:="|",  _ 
>      FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)),  _ 
>      TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Answer (score 1):

I assume your table has 4 columns

master_id, BMI1, BMI2, BMI3 and BMI4

you can generate INSERT statements using below query and then run them on your database

```
select 'insert into newTable (master_id, BMI1, BMI2, BMI3) values( ' +
   cast(master_id as varchar) + ',''' + replace(latestBMI, '|', ''',''') + ''')'
from #t
```

It generates below statements (using your sample data)

```
insert into newTable (master_id, BMI1, BMI2, BMI3) values( 251,'2008-05-08','84','26.8')
insert into newTable (master_id, BMI1, BMI2, BMI3) values( 2848,'1992-11-23','86.71','27.3')
insert into newTable (master_id, BMI1, BMI2, BMI3) values( 2026,'2002-04-16','105','31.6')
insert into newTable (master_id, BMI1, BMI2, BMI3) values( 22316,'2014-02-28','107.955','35.1')
insert into newTable (master_id, BMI1, BMI2, BMI3) values( 16633,'2005-07-04','70','25')
insert into newTable (master_id, BMI1, BMI2, BMI3) values( 9545,'1997-04-08','82.73','24.9')
```

if the columns are not integer, you can modify the SELECT statement to get what you need. But still the generated INSERT will work, even if your columns are numeric.

Comment: Sorry I'm only just learning all this so this may seem a stupid question, but how do I write that into my query?

Comment: It's OK. you need to run the first query. It returns you result, contain INSERT statement. then you need to loop on that and execute each statement to insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

After your code to import your data just use text to columns to separate it.

```
    Sub SepDelCol()
       Columns("B:B").Select
       Selection.TextToColumns _
       Destination:=Range("B:B"), _
       DataType:=xlDelimited, _
       TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
       Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
       Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
     End Sub
```

Comment: Of course. I should have thought of that. Great idea thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of complicated SQL/database-based solutions (see [Split Strings the Right Way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)), it's going to be far easier to deal with your data in VBA after the SQL statement completes.

Your code looks like it will produce a result that looks like this:

[image]

So you should loop through the results in column B and separate it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    SeparateFields ActiveSheet
End Sub

Sub SeparateFields(ws As Worksheet)
    '--- assumes your concatenated field (after your SQL
    '    statement) ends up in column B. The separated
    '    fields go in columns B, C, D.
    Dim concatFields As String
    Dim fields() As String
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim i As Long
    numRows = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To numRows
        concatFields = ws.Cells(i, 2).value
        fields = Split(concatFields, "|", , vbTextCompare)
        ws.Cells(i, 2).value = fields(0)
        ws.Cells(i, 3).value = fields(1)
        ws.Cells(i, 4).value = fields(2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I sort of resigned myself to this. You are correct it does end up like that after the extraction. Can I put the code directly under the current vba code which is on sheet1?

Comment: Yes, you can put it directly under your existing code. Add a line that says `set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`, right before you set `numRows` and it should work fine.